# How to validate application/x-www-form-urlencoded request using AWS API Gateway model scema and(or) mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am sending request to API Gateway from Slack. The request is then sent to lambda to process it. I would like to filter out invalid requests before hitting lambda, at the API Gateway level itself. The "entire" payload sent by slack is like below;

```
{
  resource: '/',
  path: '/',
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json,*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Host: 'qweehhy6xd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)',
    'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-6204af65-03e4d5b23ec5f79e0ehgfdc',
    'X-Forwarded-For': '133.237.255.123',
    'X-Forwarded-Port': '443',
    'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
    'X-Slack-Request-Timestamp': '1644474213',
    'X-Slack-Signature': 'v0=c56tghyt30c8a8ec9228a73d3849de4de9055164a3d72a1793786f8d04617ecd7'
  },
  multiValueHeaders: {
    Accept: [ 'application/json,*/*' ],
    'Accept-Encoding': [ 'gzip,deflate' ],
    'Content-Type': [ 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ],
    Host: [ 'qweehhy6xd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' ],
    'User-Agent': [ 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)' ],
    'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': [ 'Root=1-6204af65-03e4d5b87ec5f79e0ee0c632' ],
    'X-Forwarded-For': [ '133.237.255.123' ],
    'X-Forwarded-Port': [ '443' ],
    'X-Forwarded-Proto': [ 'https' ],
    'X-Slack-Request-Timestamp': [ '1644474213' ],
    'X-Slack-Signature': [
      'v0=c56tghyt30c8a8ec9228a73d3849de4de9055164a3d72a1793786f8d04617ecd7'
    ]
  },
  queryStringParameters: null,
  multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
  pathParameters: null,
  stageVariables: null,
  requestContext: {
    resourceId: 's7q8swr5fr',
    resourcePath: '/',
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    extendedRequestId: 'SPYX4GyfIAMFX2A=',
    requestTime: '10/Feb/2022:06:23:33 +0000',
    path: '/qwerty',
    accountId: '592976962544',
    protocol: 'HTTP/1.1',
    stage: 'qwerty',
    domainPrefix: 'qweehhy6xd',
    requestTimeEpoch: 1644474213489,
    requestId: 'vtg02b44-a456-4gt0-abe4-499146d32b5b',
    identity: {
      cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
      accountId: null,
      cognitoIdentityId: null,
      caller: null,
      sourceIp: '133.237.255.123',
      principalOrgId: null,
      accessKey: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationType: null,
      cognitoAuthenticationProvider: null,
      userArn: null,
      userAgent: 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)',
      user: null
    },
    domainName: 'qweehhy6xd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    apiId: 'qweehhy6xd'
  },
  body: 'parama=valuea&paramb=value_b&param_c=valuec',
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

Now, I would like to validate this string at the API Gateway level. Say, `requestContext.resourceId` is `s7q8swr5fr` in the request payload. I would like to terminate all requests where `resourceId` is not `s7q8swr5fr`. Something to note here is `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Somebody please tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you.

EDIT

I used the model below;

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema# ",
    "title": "TestModel",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "requestContext": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["resourceId", "accountId", "domainPrefix"],
            "properties": {
                "resourceId": { "type": "string", "pattern": "s7q8swr5fr" },
                "accountId": { "type": "string", "pattern": "592976962544" },
                "domainPrefix": { "type": "string", "pattern": "qweehhy6xd" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The model is then saved and mentioned under the method request configuration, like below;

[image: model_mentioned]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I already went through it

Comment: why there is a constraint to validate this inside API gateway level and why not at the function level? you can try asking here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat somebody will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

Amazon API Gateway V1 does not support request body validation of payloads with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the only supported content-type is application/json.

If the content-type isn't present in the request, then the request isn't validated.